# React - Why doesn't addEventListener work?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, addeventlistener, gatsby

I am trying to create a website by using GatsbyJS, and I got stuck whenever I need to set a onClick event to toggle a class in one of my components. As a beginner with react and gatsby, I'm having a hard time to do it.

So essentially I want to make the following JS code in React/GatsbyJS:

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.burger_menur');
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

The following code is my current code in Gatsby component. Have to say, I am using GSAP to make an animation.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tween, Timeline } from 'react-gsap';
import '../styles/burger.scss'


const Burger = () => (

  <Timeline
    target={

        <div className='burger'>
            <div className='burger_menu'>
                <div className='bar half start'></div>
                <div className='bar'></div>
                <div className='bar half end'></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
  >
    <Tween from={{ opacity: '0', marginRight: '0rem' }} to={{ opacity: '1', marginRight: '5rem' }} ease="Back.easeOut" delay={2}/>

  </Timeline>
);


export default Burger
```

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

**If you're going to go with React, don't manipulate the DOM directly**.

More specifically, don't try to act directly on any part of the DOM generated by React.

---

Here, you're using plain DOM manipulation to attach your event to elements generated by React *(also, there's a typo in your class name)*:

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.burger_menur');
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

The thing is, while it may sometimes work, **React will regenerate new elements** for your menu when it deems it necessary, **and your events listeners will be lost**.

You have to do it "the React way":

```
...
   <div className='burger'>
       <div className={`burger_menu ${this.state.isOpen? ' open' : ''}`} onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: !isOpen })}>
           <div className='bar half start'></div>
           <div className='bar'></div>
           <div className='bar half end'></div>
       </div>
   </div>
...
```

Don't forget to initialize your state with `{ isOpen: false }`

Clicking the div will toggle `this.state.isOpen`, which is used to decide whether the class-name will be `'burger_menu'` or `'burger_menu open'`.

*Note: There are more elegant ways to work with classlists when they get longer, but your component being simple and for the sake of clarity, a string template will more than do.*

---

If any of this sounds confusing, please read through the official tutorial [Intro To React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), it's very well explained and covers everything needed here.

If you're already comfortable with this and want to know more about handling events in React, the docs has you covered once again: [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Yes. The name "React" even implies that the view reacts to changes in the data model. Don't do it yourself unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Indeed — it’s important to realize this is a feature and not a limitation — **it’s the premise of React**.